# How find online users of the game in facebook javascript sdk 2.1

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm developing a puzzle game in facebook javascript sdk. I want to display online users in my game board. unfortunately FQL removed from sdk 2.1, Is any other options are there to find active users of the game? and also how to check user liked my page or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing the active users, you would have to implement your own routine - for example, you could update a timestamp whenever the user does something in your game. Everyone with a recent timestamp would count as active.

About how to check if the user liked your Page: The only way to do this is to ask for the "user_likes" permission, but you would have to go through a review process with that one and Facebook will never approve it just for that. Btw, Like Gating and incentivizing Likes is not allowed anymore according to the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). See the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) for more information.